# missing line/item in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-list

somehow I don't see an item - I did not delete it. I had a problem with number of lines limit but it was solved. However now I can't find it , not even in recycle bin of SharePoint.

any idea what should I do ?

**message:**

> "Sorry, something went wrong  No item exists at
>   http://module/list/DispForm.aspx?ID=191.  It may have been deleted or
>   renamed by another user.
>
> Web Parts Maintenance Page: If you have permission, you can use this
>   page to temporarily close Web Parts or remove personal settings. For
>   more information, contact your site administrator.  Technical Details
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.  Correlation
>   ID: 481a189e-fc89-c0de-8e3c-efd2f255b23e  Date and Time: 9/11/2017
>   8:44:28 AM

Comment: Have you checked site collection recycle bin?

Answer (score 0):

if your a site collection admin you can check the site collection recycle bin for the item as well.